# NSSearchField close button doesn't close the NSSearchField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

I have to press over the X button very fast to close it actually

This is an untouched NSSearchField... is this a bug or this functionality needs to be special handled?

[image]

Comment: That's the *Clear* button, isn't it?

Comment: but if i press it 2times fast, than the search field closes (look at end of the gif)

Comment: I don't see it closing; it just changes appearance.

Comment: Kind of strange why they didn't use **⌫** instead actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(X)` button inside the search field is actually a clear button — ( it deletes text within the box ). There's actually no `close` button for it that I'm aware of, although you might be able to come up with something that hides and shows it I suppose.

Also, the magnifying glass doesn't zoom either, in case you were wondering... it's simply a decoration signifying "Search".

Comment: very funny with the zoom lens:)) but what is irritating me, is that when i tap it 2 times fast enough, the search field closes (resignes first responder)

Comment: Is the behavior just in your app? When I try it in Character Viewer it's hard to know if that's happening because it's fairly quick. :)

Comment: its the same, i guess its a feature

Comment: Yeah it does do it... the "Search" word moves over to the right a bit and the (x) disappears.